# How to Read Hive Table in Spark without header

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, header

I am trying to read one hive table in pyspark but I am getting header as well that I do not want.

**File.csv**

```
Id,Name
1,A
2,B
3,C
4,D
```

**Hive Table**

I build hive table with `tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")` and in Hive I am getting data correctly so there is no issue with Hive.

I am facing issue while I am reading this table in pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Spark-11374](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11374) jira reported for this issue and closed as `won't fix`.

**Possible ways to do this are:**

**`1.You can directly read the HDFS file:`**

```
spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter",",").csv("<hdfs_path>").show()
```

**`2.using hive query:`**

```
spark.sql("select * from <table_name> where <col_name1> != 'id'").show()
```